# Architecture for passing messages from one system to another

Tags: c#, wcf, architecture, queue

I am starting to work on a piece of development today, and was looking to see if this is the optimal solution:

I have 3 systems:

SystemA : third party system which handles order management.

SystemB : internal system used for shipping orders that have been placed on systemA for a particular supplier (used for shipping old suppliers orders)

SystemC : internal system used for shipping orders that have been placed on systemA for a particular supplier. (used for shipping new suppliers orders)

So systemB and systemC both need to pull orders from systemA but only want to pull orders based on a systemID, which is fine.

**Goals:** 
1. Avoid Duplication of orders sent to old (B) and new (C) systems
2. speed
3. Allow for new systems to be added

I plan on building an intermediary service the retrieves orders from systemA using BL that I already have written.  From there it will add it to a queue.  System B and C will them make a web request to some endpoint using their system ID to get their latest messages for their system.  Each system can them process the messages/orders and import them into their systems.

**So my questions:**

1. Would masstransit or nservicebus work in this situation?
2. IS there an example of this sort of thing anywherE? I could not find one?
3. Does this structure sound ok or would there be a better way to do it?
4. Would I be better using a table queue and WCF to acheive this?